# How is SPI is used for TFT diaplays (and in general for other peripherals)

Tags: spi, pi

I need to hook up several TFT displays so all display the same thing. The displays accept SPI interface and I find myself needing more details as to how the SPI (and somewhat the driver) works with relation to TFT screens.

**My Assumptions follow (please correct inaccuracy/misconceptions):**

**1)** Big Picture: There is a driver specific to the TFT SPI interface hardware that maps the screen to a specific device context.  The driver is installed and all of the SPI interface details are hidden from the application at that point. All the program knows is that there is device X and here are its programming interface.

**2)** The SPI controller on the TFT is the **Secondary**, or **Peripheral**, SPI interface, the computer or controller it's hooked up to is the **Primary** SPI interface.

**3)** The Peripheral SPI driver is on the computer or controller and "sees and talks to" the Primary SPI SPI interface only.

**4** When Data are to be displayed, the application sends the data, through a DC that that was made available via device driver, to the SPI Primary interface.  The SPI Primary interface formats the data for SPI transmission and the data are sent to the secondary SPI interface.  The secondary SPI interface then formats/sends the data to the Peripheral that it's attached to.  The SPI terminus is on the TFT in my case, I am only conceptualizing seperation here.

**5** The data and signals that are sent to/received from the Secondary SPI interface are only visible to the SPI Primary and Secondary interfaces.

**6** There is a chip select line that allows for multiple parallel peripherals to "know" when the primary is talking to them.

**7** I have not gotten to touch screen input.  I'll post that on another thread.

The questions below assume all of the above is correct.  If not, tell me and I'll correct the statement before moving on.

**Questions:**

**1)** Can I select all of the peripherals and then do one "write" to send the same screen to each one at the same time, even though the driver probably "sees" all of the screens as a different DC?

**2)** If I don't have enough pinouts for all of my peripherals, can i leverage another controller board to extend my pinouts?  I.E. Computer SPI Primary controller >> controller board Secondary controller >> controller board Primary controller >> Peripheral Secondary controller.

**3)** I have read that the max cable distance is 10 meters between controller and peripjheral.  But I have also read that it's more like 10cm.  Clarification for this is also needed.

I have not attempted anything yet.  I am hoping to get some more information before I pinout wrong and ruin a TFT screen, a controller, or a computer.

Comment: What books and / or articles have you read?

Comment: I am currently reading a few books on Micro controller to peripheral SPI communications.  They are helping with the generics of SPI, but not TFT (which I assume I could get a lot of from the DATA sheet for the specific display).  Really I am more interested in knowing the answers to the specific questions posed.  and I have read that the max cable distance is 10 meters between controller and peripjheral.  But I also read that it's more like 10cm.  So I am adding that to the list.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be about programming.

Comment: Alejandro,Yes, it is, I need to understand the interface in order to program it.  The programming has a physical aspect to it, yes, programming for them requires understanding that I lack.  And I thought maybe someone here may have already had a similar application for SPI that I could learn from.